# How long is it reasonable to wait for an unconfirmed transaction?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, time

Approximately 18 hours ago I made 2 transactions of similar value (approx 0.02 BTC each). This was sending bitcoins to 2 seperate address's. The transaction fees were approx 1% of the values sent. Any transactions I have conducted in the past have been more or less instant, so I am a little concerned that 18 hours have elapsed with 0 out of 3 confirmations on both.

What do I do now? Wait longer, if so for how long?

I have seen suggestions of sending the payment again and increasing the transaction fee, but how can I be sure that after I send the new payment then the original wont clear after it also, meaning double funds have been sent. If I do redo the transaction how much do I increase the fee by?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is not usually intended to add the duplicated link too?

Comment: It has now confirmed after 4 days.